# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError android viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was working with the viewpager app which can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#fragment). I am running it on android 2.3.3 so I have changed `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.FragmentManager;` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;` but my app force closes. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.android.animationsdemo.CardFlipActivity
    at com.example.android.animationsdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's wrong?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.animationsdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private class Sample {
    private CharSequence title;
    private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;

    public Sample(int titleResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
        this.activityClass = activityClass;
        this.title = getResources().getString(titleResId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title.toString();
    }
}

/**
 * The collection of all samples in the app. This gets instantiated in {@link
 * #onCreate(android.os.Bundle)} because the {@link Sample} constructor needs access to {@link
 * android.content.res.Resources}.
 */
private static Sample[] mSamples;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instantiate the list of samples.
    mSamples = new Sample[]{
            new Sample(R.string.title_crossfade, CrossfadeActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_card_flip, CardFlipActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_screen_slide, ScreenSlideActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_zoom, ZoomActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.title_layout_changes, LayoutChangesActivity.class),
    };

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sample>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            mSamples));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Launch the sample associated with this list position.
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, mSamples[position].activityClass));
}
}
```

Comment: What you have at line number 63 on MainActivity.java, post your code as well.

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: Are you using any library project?

Comment: Please specify your code here

Comment: @Ben i'm not using progaurd

Answer (score 0):

My guess is here:

```
 mSamples = new Sample[]{
        new Sample(R.string.title_crossfade, CrossfadeActivity.class),
        new Sample(R.string.title_card_flip, CardFlipActivity.class),
        new Sample(R.string.title_screen_slide, ScreenSlideActivity.class),
        new Sample(R.string.title_zoom, ZoomActivity.class),
        new Sample(R.string.title_layout_changes, LayoutChangesActivity.class),
};
```

Do you have all of those activities in your app? And are they all defined in your manifest? And if you're copying the tutorial bit by bit, make sure you have everything they're using in your app as well, such as the strings they're using.